# Rails table indexes are not foreign keys in database as expected - why?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have created tables for user and attendance (Users, Attendances) and all is good. A user has many attendances and an attendance belongs to user. The code works and Rails works but there is one big issue.

Inspecting the user_id field in the attendances table, it is NOT listed as a foreign key. Looking at other projects I notice this is always the case - Rails marks these as just integers.

This is all good if I am ONLY using the database with Rails, but what if I need to use this database in another program (say in a pure Ruby service program that runs in the background). Is there any way to get rails to mark these as foreign keys? Would this break Rails? It does the same thing in MySQL by the way - "foreign keys" are actually just integers and not marked as such.

My migration for the user_id was simply: rails g migration add_user_id_to_attendances user_id:integer

EDIT: I feel this is NOT a duplicate because it is asking about possible changes that can be made in order to actually add a Foreign key, whereas the "duplicate"'s question proposition is simply "Is this true or isn't it?" This question is intended to solicit solutions to the problem as opposed to establishing it as a fact. Closing this down will prevent me from reaching a solution and deny other users an answer.

Comment: I inspected the tables using pgAdmin, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) gem.

> Foreigner introduces a few methods to your migrations for adding and removing foreign key constraints. It also dumps foreign keys to schema.rb.

```
add_foreign_key(from_table, to_table, options)
remove_foreign_key(from_table, options)
```

Comment: Superb! This is exactly what I was after. DO you know though, is there any support (in Rails 4) for defaulting to marking the id as a foreign key when created, or can I only do it with the gem you mentioned? (For future reference) - and will I have to rollback before using Foreigner?

Comment: See the following section in the Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#active-record-and-referential-integrity:  TLDR ActiveRecord(Rails) doesn't provide any helpers for this, but you can use `execute` to run raw SQL commands in your migration or use the gem @screenmutt mentioned.

Comment: I used the Immigrant Gem (Foreigner add-on) to alter my exisiting INT keys and make them foreign keys. The command was simply "rails generate immigration AddKeys". As simple as that. Checking in pgAdmin, my foreign keys are now actually foreign keys in the db.